# Notifications go crazy when using dual monitors with an ATI Radeon

Tags: 11.10, unity, ati, multiple-monitors, fglrx

When you configure the system with dual monitor xinerama, everything works fine exept the notification area, goes crazy when I try to raise or lower the volume for example that flashes across the systray appears on both screens.

I use: ATI Radeon HD 5670, With Ubuntu 11.10 x64 clean, not any strange soft or theme, only ATI driver configured in dual monitor with xinerama.

*Note: Sorry, for my bad english.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this driver:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-1112-linux.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: i have installed the lasted version of the catalyst, and my dual screen + fglrx are working, the notification area of the unity are the problem, i want to know if this have solution, else i can use widgets to doing the same functions.